# When should I create Solr connection in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, rsolr

I'm accessing Solr in a Ruby on Rails application by using [rsolr](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr) (not Sunspot). I create the local solr object that I use to send requests like this:

```
solr = RSolr.connect(:url => "http://localhost:8983/solr")
```

as far as I understand, this is not really a connection but just an object that will issue requests on demand, so it shouldn't be expensive to keep it initialized and it should never *disconnect*. According to that, it should be ok to have one global solr object, create it at start time and forget about it. Right? But maybe it's not thread safe?

When should I create the solr connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that the `RSolr.connect` method really does is sanitize and save the options that you're using.  You can see that method [here.](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr/blob/master/lib/rsolr/client.rb#L5)  It's passed a new connection object (which, notably, doesn't have an `initialize` method, so it's not doing anything when created) and the options that you pass to `RSolr.connect`.

So yes, you're right -- no harm at all in connecting once and leaving it connected forever hanging around in a variable somewhere.  (For example, I memoize the result of `RSolr.connect` [in my Solr/Rails app.](https://github.com/cpence/rletters/blob/master/lib/solr/connection.rb))